# declare java.util.Map into json-schema

Tags: java, json, maven, jsonschema, jsonschema2pojo

I need to map a `java.util.Map` instance into a JSON-schema that is used by `org.jsonschema2pojo` maven plugin to create a POJO.

I didn't find a good and simple solution for this.

Could someone help me please?

This is my actual json-schema file

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Response",
    "description": "A Response object",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "result": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "describes response status"
        },
        "msg": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "user msgs"
        }
    },
    "required": ["result"],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

I need to add a field `"errors"` that is converted into a `java.util.Map<String, String>` in Java.

Comment: Could you please declare more about your question? From my understanding, you have a JSON schema as described, and you have a map probably looks like: "errors":{"type":"string"}, then you want to add the map into your JSON schema file and use it in jsonschema2pojo, right? If I have any misunderstanding please give some example, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `additionalProperties` does the job. 
You can declare an errors property of type `Map<String, Object>` for example like this (this is yaml now):

```
...
properties:
  errors:
    type: object
    additionalProperties:
      type: object
```

You don't specify the type of the keys, since this describes a json document, which naturally has strings as keys on objects.

instead of `type: object` you can also do `type: string` for `Map<String, String>` or reference another definition if you have your own type as values in that map.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for reply. I found and tried additionalProperties but I can't change the name and then into the generated pojo, the field "additionalProperties" is mapped with @JsonIgnore and I don't want it.

Comment: Hm, maybe a quirk in the code generator.
What name do you mean? Can you paste an excerpt of what you tried and what got generated from it?